# Perlin Noise scaling

Tags: python, math, noise, perlin-noise

I am working on this 2D game in Python and I want there to be an infinite randomly generated map, but one that can be regenerated using a seed.
So first of all I want to be able to render any part of the map without rendering other stuff, so if I want to find the tile type number for coordinate (50,100) I should be able to do that without having to calculate any other tiles. I tried using different noise functions to generate the map, but I have not been able scale the distance between "peaks and valleys" in any implementation. The effect is that the landscape has too many too small patches of grass and dirt, etc.

Looking at the "simple" implementation below, how would you "scale" this? I am not a mathematician and simply can't figure it out myself.

```
def noise(x, y, max):
    n=x*331+y*337
    n=(n<<13)^n
    nn=(n*(n*n*41333 +53307781)+1376312589)&0x7fffffff
    return ((1.0-(nn/1073741824.0))+1)/2.0 * max
```

Comment: From the description of the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Algorithm) it sounds like you'd need to generate an infinite grid to store all the unit vector gradients in order to do what you want -- which obviously isn't possible since it would require infinite memory. Besides that, doing all the computations involved to determine a sample value does not sound like a practical thing to try to implement in pure Python.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it does already work. Using the function above I generate the tiles for what is on the screen at any moment, but nothing more (about 40*80 = 3200 tiles). I don't store them and they don't exist when the user isn't looking. It works fine and the map seemingly goes on forever. My problem is the way the distance between the peaks and valleys in the function, making the map looking kind of "cramped".

Comment: I was talking about something that generated Perlin Noise -- which I don't think you're doing in your function. To scale what you have, seems like you could just round the x & y values to the four nearest points on the grid and then bi-linearly interpolate the value for the actual point which lies somewhere within the boundary of the four actually on the grid.

Comment: Well maybe I understood you wrong, but that's not quite how the game works. First of I cant promise you that it is a Perlin noise function, but from the output it is **clearly** a noise function. I use a grid of 32px * 32px "tiles" and I want the type of each tile to be determined by a function. Look at this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRamnpPCHKI

Comment: To my understanding, the "granularity" of the finally generated Perlin noise depends less on the random number generator used, but more on the weights for the octaves; in order to have the output "softer", one would decrease the weights for the higher octaves and increase the weights for the lower octaves.